# std::vector crash?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

Wrote a small program to test vectors and I don't understand why this is crashing, could someone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void print(int* i)
{
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<int*>* intPtr;

        intPtr->push_back(new int(1));
        intPtr->push_back(new int(2));
        intPtr->push_back(new int(3));

        std::for_each(intPtr->begin(), intPtr->end(), print);
}
```

Ignore the memory leaks for now, this was just a quick example.

Comment: `intPtr` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: (1) change `std::vector<int*>* intPtr;` to `std::vector<int*>* intPtr = new std::vector<int*>();` then (2) [Read this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf).

Comment: What on earth is wrong with `std::vector<int>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int*> intPtr; // no need to make this a pointer.
```

Comment: In this example there's no need, but I made this a pointer because this was a replica of a problem I was having in a bigger project on a smaller scale.

Comment: @Shippage : There's simply no usecase for `new std::vector<>`, _ever_.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize `intPtr`. Try changing that line to:

```
std::vector<int*>* intPtr = new std::vector<int*>;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize it like so:

```
std::vector<int*> *intPtr = new vector<int*>();
```